# How integrating CAS Protocol with Microsoft .NET6 APIs c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, cas

I have some APIs written with .NET6.
I want that only some of my APIs are authorized with the CAS protocol.

I am looking for documentation or examples but I found only very old examples with old technologies and I cannot figure out which steps I need to perform in .NET6.
Did some of your have the same problem? could you advice me on how to proceed?

Thank you in advance! Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you advice me on how to proceed?

Not sure, which document you have found. Regarding [central authentication service (CAS)](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/central-authentication-service/), which is least popular as compare to other authentication protocal. However, you can get the [implementation details here.](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/central-authentication-service/)

> I found only very old examples with old technologies and I cannot
> figure out which steps I need to perform in .NET6.

Sample Project:

The key part of the CAS is within your builder.Services class you would require to include following code snippet:

```
.AddCAS(options =>
    {
        options.CasServerUrlBase = builder.Configuration["Authentication:CAS:ServerUrlBase"];
        options.SaveTokens = builder.Configuration.GetValue("Authentication:CAS:SaveTokens", false);
        var protocolVersion = builder.Configuration.GetValue("Authentication:CAS:ProtocolVersion", 3);
        if (protocolVersion != 3)
        {
            options.ServiceTicketValidator = protocolVersion switch
            {
                1 => new Cas10ServiceTicketValidator(options),
                2 => new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(options),
                _ => null
            };
        }

        options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            if (context.Identity == null)
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            // Map claims from assertion
            var assertion = context.Assertion;
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, assertion.PrincipalName));
            if (assertion.Attributes.TryGetValue("display_name", out var displayName))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, displayName));
            }

            if (assertion.Attributes.TryGetValue("email", out var email))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
```

You can get more details on [asp.net core 6 complete example](https://github.com/akunzai/GSS.Authentication.CAS/blob/main/samples/AspNetCoreSample/Program.cs) you could [check here.](https://github.com/akunzai/GSS.Authentication.CAS/blob/main/samples/AspNetCoreSample/Program.cs)

**Note:** Please be informed that, this is not a official sample. Anything within the sample would be your responsibility and venture.